# How to drop the row index from plot in pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my pandas dataframe, which contains 2 columns and 120 rows. I would like the first column of my data to take the x-axis and the second one to be the y-axis. However, when I attempt to plot it using plt.plot, the pandas default row index is getting plotted as the x-axis, and the two columns are plotted as two distinct plots along the y-axis. Below is a screenshot of my dataframe and the resulting plot. How can I plot only my data and not the row indices created by pandas?

[image: Output Code]

Comment: Can you please provide the data as text, not image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `x` and `y`:

```
df.plot(x='Base.Time (s)', y='WE(1).Current (A)')
```

Or, define your time as index:

```
df.set_index('Base.Time (s)').plot()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to work with column indices instead of their names? as it would make things easier.

Comment: `df.set_index(df.columns[0]).plot()`?